# Hamburger for Mobile Devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]I have been searching for a solution to my particular problem without much success. I am attempting to code a website in bootstrap 3. I have used an inverse navbar which renders as desired on a desktop/laptop computer.

There are menu items to the left as well as two items to the left (register and login). The registration directs to a registration page, the login results in a dropdown login box.

However, I would like for the menu to render as a hamburger on mobile devices, only showing menu-items when it the hamburger is tapped.On this menu the registration and login links can be below the rest of the menu links.

The code I starting with is below and I have included a screen shot. Any assistance is greatly apreciated.

```
<div class="content row">
  <div class="container">


<header class="clearfix">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">             
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul><!-- nav navbar-nav -->    
             <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Log In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
                                Username:<br /><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" /> 
                                <br /><br /> 
                                Password:<br /><input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
                                <br /><br /> 
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Login" /> 
                                </form> 

                            </div><!--drop dwon menu nav -->

                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div><!--nav-collapse collapse-->

</div><!-- navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top-->


</header><!-- header -->


  </div><!--container-->
</div><!--content row -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your classes / element hierarchy a bit

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul><!-- nav navbar-nav -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Log In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <form action="login.php" method="post">
                            Username:<br /><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" />
                            <br /><br />
                            Password:<br /><input type="password" name="password" value="" />
                            <br /><br />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Login" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--container-fluid-->
</nav>
```

---

Fiddle - http://www.bootply.com/render/sdyDKCyOnA

Comment: Thanks for the help @potatopeelings. When I implement the solution above, I notice that, on a full screen, the navbar disappears completely. I see that this does not happen in your fiddle so I need to see if something else in my code might be causing this.

Comment: To the DOM Explorer! By the way check if it's actually hiding under one of the your existing layers too (I spent a bunch of time on something similar last week). Cheers!

Comment: Man, I cannot find anything that would be causing the navbar to completely disappear full screen. I even cleared cash and restarted web server.

Comment: will do man! thanks for the help. I would prefer to hire out the front-end of this thing between you and me. I am a backend developer being pushied into front-end development. Thanks again.

Comment: Man, I have stripped this down to the bare minimum and nothing is working!!

Comment: :-) @jjones150 - have that bare minimum thing? post it over at bootply.